# Derivative of convolution of $ r $ and $ s $ times continuously differentiable functions.

Tags: derivatives, continuity, convolution

I have a problem with proving part (ii) of the following theorem. How to start the induction step to prove it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use induction on $n=r+s$. The base case is that the convolution of two continuous functions is continuous. The induction step is (i).

Comment: In part (i), how can we be sure that f' is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Lord Shark the Unknown.

Comment: I presume $\Bbb T$ is the circle, and so compact. Any continuous function from a compact metric space to $\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous.